# How to post a request with python specifying the body raw

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests, postman

I am trying to send a JSON object using python but I am getting 422 error. Meanwhile, with postman I am able to post the JSON via the API:
First I enter the authentication in the Authorization and in the body I specify raw and choose JSON then I post the JSON object and get a 200 response.

[image]

But with python:

```
endpoint = "some endpoint"
url = host + endpoint
headers={"Accept": "application/json",
         "Authorization": f"Bearer {bearer_token}"}
        
order = json.dumps(json_object, ensure_ascii=False)
send_data = requests.post(url, json=order, headers=headers)
print(send_data.json())
        
if send_data.status_code==200:
   print("Order successfully sent")
else:
   print(f"The following error was encountered. Error: {send_data.status_code}")
```

What could be wrong? please advise

Comment: Don't use `json.dumps`. Use `json=json_object`

Comment: That didnt work

Comment: What is there in json_object? A dictionary? Why did it not work, any error?

Comment: Looks like it did work, but I throw an error on the country key, I guess I will adjust the country and try again. One moment

Answer (score 1):

try

```
headers={"Accept": "application/json",
         "Authorization": f"Bearer {bearer_token}"}

send_data = requests.post(url, data=order, headers=headers)
```